# Trouble with posting slidify to Dropbox

Tags: r, dropbox, slidify

I created a `slidify` slideshow, but when I am trying to drop in into my dropbox account into Public folder I get a `warning`:

```
publish("Slides", host = "dropbox")

Creating slide directory at ~/Dropbox/Public/Slides
Copying files to ~/Dropbox/Public/Slides
[1] FALSE
Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(".", drop_dir, overwrite = F, recursive = TRUE) :
  'recursive' will be ignored as 'to' is not a single existing directory
2: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '~/Dropbox/Public/Slides', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I tried to create a `hard symbolic link` as http://thiagosilva.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/installing-slidify-on-a-windows-machine/ suggests.

But the warning is still there...

Any ideas?

Best Regards!

Comment: Try `file.exists("~/Dropbox/Public/Slides")` and see what you get.

Comment: Worst case, you can just drag and drop your slide directory to the Public folder in Dropbox. That is all that the publish_dropbox function does :)

Comment: @Ramnath Thanks:) But I wonder why does the `gvisMotionChart` only works for me when I publish it to `RPubs`? Am I doing something wrong? Btw, thanks for the great package!!

Comment: Can you provide me with a link to your slides on dropbox? I have had problems hosting HTML in dropbox, which is why I tend to avoid it. But, if you send me a link I can take a look.

Comment: @Ramnath Sure! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31405375/index.html is the slides. Motion chart is not working. But it works if I publish to http://rpubs.com/PaulK/8251

Comment: @Ramnath Ops..My fault...gvisMotionChart works for me at dropbox. But I still cant connect to github. I read your comments at https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/128 but could not resolve SSH issue I guess..

Comment: @Ramnath Just to add... gvisMotionChart only works if I ``copy the public link` and view the slides, but it does not work if I just click on it inside dropbox.

Comment: The motionchart won't appear locally, due to flash restrictions (which need to be explicitly relaxed). If you run from a local server, it should work. Github SSH issues is a different beast. Post an issue on github issues page for Slidify and I can take a look.